# What algorithm does OLA and UBER use for allotting taxis

Tags: dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, scheduling

More specifically :
lets say i have 5 taxis , each available for booking at t=0; i have two days (48 hrs) with me how can I maximise their booking . I may not be able to clarify the question , this was some interview question but the context is how to schedule the taxis for max profit. I gave a algo to run at t=0 but interviewer asked for a dynamic solution a solution that runs every time . I dont know how to do that any which topic of Computer Science deals with such problems .

Comment: "I dont know how to do that any which topic of Computer Science deals with such problems" "Tags: ... scheduling" ?

Comment: just a guess , tags cant be empty

Comment: If you don't know what the question is asking, how do you plan to answer it?  How do you expect us to?  The best approach might depend on the specifics of the problem statement.

Comment: yes you are right , but i thought someone by reading the title can also answer the question if he has been in that field